# Loading Javascript into AJAX generated div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I'm trying to load Javascript into a div that has been generated through AJAX and filled with an external PHP file.

Here is the navigation I am using to load the AJAX div, and my PHP content:

```
<div id="portfolioContent">
  <div id="portfoliotabContainer">
    <ul id="portfolioTabs">
      <li><a id="dashboardTab" href="./portfolio/portfoliocontent/dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a id="casedetailsTab" href="./portfolio/portfoliocontent/casedetails.php">Case Details</a></li>
      <li><a id="correspondenceTab" href="./portfolio/portfoliocontent/correspondence.php">Correspondence</a></li>
      <li><a id="pleadingTab" href="./portfolio/portfoliocontent/pleading.php">Pleading</a></li>
      <li><a id="discoveryTab" href="./portfolio/portfoliocontent/discovery.php">Discovery</a></li>
      <li><a id="expensesTab" href="./portfolio/portfoliocontent/expenses.php">Expenses</a></li>
      <li><a id="indexTab" href="./portfolio/portfoliocontent/docindex.php">Document Index</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I need the hyperlink to load and fill the generated div, but also call an external Javascript file so my scripts work within the generated div.

Here is my script:

```
$(function () {
  $("#portfolioTabs li a").live("click", function () {
    var pagecontent = $(document.createElement("div"));
    pagecontent.load(
    $(this).attr("href"));
    $(".insideContent").html(pagecontent);
    $(".portfolioContent").animate({
      height: "110%"
    });
    $(".insideContent").animate({
      bottom: "0px"
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I've looked into this and I understand that I can load is dynamically, but I'm unsure of the simplest way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are assigning the content to another element when it is not loaded yet.

You can use the callback function of [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for that:

```
pagecontent.load($(this).attr("href"), function() {
        // this gets executed when the `load` is complete
        $(".insideContent").html(pagecontent);      

        $(".portfolioContent").animate({                    
            height: "110%"                               
        });                                                
        $(".insideContent").animate({
            bottom: "0px"
        });
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to implement this. I'm fairly weak when it comes to advanced JavaScript like this. Any further instruction?

Comment: @user2109237 No, this is all you need, you load the content in `pagecontent` and when that is done (the callback function), you load it in `.insideContent`. There is nothing else you need to change / do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like `$.ajax`. This allows you to asynchronously load content into your page without a page reload, which sounds like what you want.

Within your event handler, you would probably want something like

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        $(".insideContent").html(data);
    }
});
```

Note that everything that depends on the data loading must be placed **within** the anonymous function where I update the html.

Comment: _Note that everything that depends on the data loading must be placed within the anonymous function where I update the html._


I'm not entirely sure what you mean here - could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have set the `success` property to an anonymous function. The code in this function will be run when jQuery successfully receives a response from the server. Therefore, all code that depends on that data (in the response) needs to be in (or called by) the anonymous function